# create a backup table with all parameter

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to move the data from one table `TABLE5` another one `TABLE5_BKP`.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE5_BKP AS SELECT * FROM TABLE5;
```

The table created and the data moved. when I checked the constraints,

The primary key,foreign key etc are not generated but all other constraints like,

```
SYS_C2211111    Check   "COLUMN1" IS NOT NULL
```

etc are created. What to do in this case? Need to create the primary key,foreign key etc separately? What about indexes and other parameters, which I was not able to check.

Comment: Yes you need to create that separately. You can however use `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` to retrieve that information and re-create the necessary DDL script

Answer (score 0):

You can't implicitly create PK, FK, Indexes, etc. just using

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT *...
```

You have to specify them after creating. Also I suggest you to use oracle tools, like exp/imp, data pump, etc. if you want to move the database structure from one database to another.